# Image changing loop not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a JavaScript that is supposed to change my header image every three seconds. For some reason nothing happens when I'm opening my page.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <script src="changeImage.js"></script>
        <title>Mikael Mattsson</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img id="headerImg" src="images/header-image.png" alt="Header image" width="100%" hight="100%">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var images = [];
images[0] = "images/header-image.png";
images[1] = "images/header-image2.png";
var x = 0;
function imageChanger(){
    var img = document.getElementById("headerImg");
    img.src = images[x];
    x++;
    if (x > images.length){
        x = 0;
    }

    setTimeout("imageChanger()", 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `x > images.length` should be `x >= images.length`.
2. `setTimeout("imageChanger()", 3000);` must be changed to `setTimeout(imageChanger, 3000);`

Comment: just one explanation for the person who asked the question: `"imageChanger()"` is a string, `imageChanger` is a reference to the function

Comment: Well there is still the inital call to `imageChanger()` missing so this will never start.

Comment: Thanks guys! This worked out great! Can't believe I put the call to the function INSIDE the function. Stupid.. Anyway thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You call the `setTimeout` inside the function but never call the function. So the timeout is never set, hence the function is not called through the timeout.

I recommend using `setInterval` above `setTimeout` in your case since you want to have the function executed repeatedly. Also you could improve the way you increase `x`.

```
var x = 0;
function imageChanger() {
    var img = document.getElementById("headerImg");
    x = (x + 1) % images.length; // Make sure x is never larger than images.length
    img.src = images[x];
}

// Start calling the function after a delay of 3000ms
setInterval(imageChanger, 3000);​​​​
```

I also recommend using a better name than `x` for your counter variable, but that is up to you!

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You need to change two things.

First, you need to call the imageChanger function at least once to kick off the code. At the end of your script, add:

```
imageChanger();
```

Your code may work from there. However, instead of passing a string to setTimeout(), you should instead pass a reference to the function itself:

```
setTimeout(imageChanger, 3000);
```

You should be all set. Let me know if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
setTimeout("imageChanger()", 3000);
```

And add

```
window.onload=function() {

  setInterval(imageChanger, 3000);
}
```

Outside the function

And as pointed out, change > to >=